# Scanner input + do-while loop behaving very strangely

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I've got this code:

```
Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String word;
do
{
    word = inputScanner.next();
    System.out.println(word + ": " + dict.contains(word));
}
while (word != "@");
```

It's pretty straight-forward, but the loop is NOT terminating after receiving a `@` input from the user. I've seen other people complaining that `Scanner` is error-prone and can give unexpected results, but that doesn't explain why `dict.contains(word)` functions perfectly while the `while (word != "@")` condition is not doing a thing...

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `==` to compare strings; use [String#equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead.

```
...
while (!word.equals("@"));
```

Comment: Wow, do I feel dumb. I just assumed String objects handled the `==` operator like `String.equals()`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the .equals() method rather than the == operation.  "==" operations are used to compare primitives like boolean, int, long, ect and **references**.

A String is an object so Java assumes you want to compare the reference value rather than the value contained in the string.  Also remember that you cannot compare Long, Integer, Double ect with the == operator either.